Converting Html+css content to pdf in Django project
Converting HTml+CSS content into pdf using python libraries
For converting HTml+CSS content to pdf in my django project, i tried ReportLab, xhtml2pdf etc, but they are not giving 100% matching output if CSS is involved. pdfkit+wkhtmltopdf works really fine, but it cannot be installed using pip. Are there any libraries or modules related to python, which converts HTml+CSS content into pdf with 100% match. Or any other ways to solve this issue?
Thank u in advance...

Run "pdfkit+wkhtmltopdf" using subprocess
